# Understanding ようにも in this context

Tags: grammar

> 随分前から、ついてきている〈レギオン〉がいる。
>
> 何故か襲撃はしてこない。斥候か監視目的とも考えたが、他の〈レギオン〉を呼び寄せる**でもなく**ひたすら単騎で後方を追従している。待ち伏せ**ようにも**こちらが止まると向こうもその間足を止めるし、おそらく引き返してもそれは同じだ。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

How should I understand the ようにも here? It’s not the construction ようにも……ない which is familiar to me.
By the way, does the でもなく mean the same as ことなく?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### ようにも

It is the usage of the following definition of [にも](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82/#jn-168075)

> 《接続助詞「に」＋係助詞「も」》（多く「…うにも」の形で）逆接の仮定条件を表す。「運転しよう―車がない」

Generally X(よ)うにもY means Y prevents or conflicts with (trying to do) X.

Examples:

- パソコンを買おうにもお金がない Even though I'm willing to buy a PC, I don't have money.
- 引っ越しをしようにも暇がない Even if I try to move my house, I don't have time for it.

In the sentence of the question, it says the speaker may want to stop and confront the follower, but the follower stopping following makes it impossible.

### でもなく

It also has the following [dictionary entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/#jn-152535) as a phrase.

> ［連語］《断定の助動詞「だ」の連用形＋係助詞「も」＋補助形容詞「ない」》
>
> １ そのことを一例として否定しながら、他のことをも否定する意を表す。「本を読む―・く一日無駄に過ごす」

In the particular context, it should be the same as ことなく = without. But でもなく has a nuance of 'not particularly ...ing' rather than just 'without ...ing'.

Examples:

- 文句を言うわけでもなく黙々と作業した Without particularly complaining, I worked silently.
- それは特に報酬があるわけでもなく、ただの暇つぶしだ It does not give any particular reward, just a killing time.

I think Xでもなく is used naturally when X is something usually expected under the circumstances. In the sentence, the follower may well call other レギオン, but without doing so, keeps following alone.

Comment: Thank you. In your examples, you used わけでもなく. So are わけでもなく and でもなく the same?

Comment: @chinoalpha Practically yes, but it seems でもなく is less natural e.g. in 特に理由があるでもなく. It is usable for animate subject/action type of verb. わけでもなく seems versatile. Your case can be 呼び寄せるわけでもなく.