# Question about どうにも

Tags: grammar

In どうにも, what does the にも mean?

When I looked up definitions of the word, this にも appeared in the explanations as well:

> 1. （他人は何と見ようと、そういう事は）どうであれ。
>    「―ここは居心地が悪い」
> 2. 《後に打消しを伴って》ほかのどんな状態**にも**。「いくら頑張っても―ならない」。どうしよう**にも**。どうしても。「―打開策が無い」

Is this a shortening of にしても?

I'm also a little confused about what exactly 「ほかのどんな状態にも」and「どうしようにも」mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, にも works somewhat like an emphatic "quoting" expression similar to といっても (see [Understanding ようにも in this context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94786/5010)). も is commonly used as part of a total negation, as in 何もない ("There is nothing") and どこにもいかない ("I'll go to nowhere"). Therefore, どうにも is basically like "no mater (one says) how". If used in a negative sentence, it sounds like "in no way".

- Looks like the first definition explains どうにも as a variant of どうも meaning "somehow" or "anyway". Another example is どうにも困りました ("Well, this is quite a problem!").
- どうにも in the second definition is a variant of どうしても or "in no way".  どうにもならない is a set phrase that literally means "become (something) in no way", but it's typically translated as "amounts to nothing". どうしようにも means "no matter how one tries".

> Is this a shortening of にしても?

What does this mean? どうにしても makes no sense. にしても exists as a colloquial abbreviation of それにしても, but this has nothing to do with どうにも.

Comment: I see! I saw one definition for どうにも listed as どのようにしても on this website, https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82 so I thought maybe it was a contraction of that phrase. I understand now.